# Creación de objetos dentro de bucle

Tags: c#, poo, objeto

¿alguien me puede decir como crear objetos dentro de un bucle con distinto nombre de objeto en c#?
El bucle crea tantos objetos como pida el usuario.
necesito referenciar los objetos para acceder a ellos según su nombre(pidiéndolo por teclado por ejemplo) y es necesario que sean distintos. lo que quiero es dentro del `switch` en el **case 1** crear el objeto **coche** con distintos nombres por ejemplo pidiéndolo por consola(lo que pretendo es que los objetos tengan distintos nombres únicamente), el proyecto tiene constructor vacío y constructor con todos los parámetros, pego el código de del bucle `do{}while()`:

```
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la opción que desea:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Introducir un coche.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Mostrar los coches almacenados.");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Mostrar los coches de una marca.");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Sobrecargar operador + para que al sumar con un coche, el coche se agregue al array.");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Sobrecargar el operador - para eliminar un coche del array.");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Salir del programa.");
        string opcion_ejercicio = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (opcion_ejercicio)
        {
            case "1":       //lista.agregarcoche(coche)
                Console.WriteLine("Introduzca un identificador para el coche:");
                var identificador = Console.ReadLine();
                string modelo = PedirModelo();
                string matricula = PedirMatricula();
                string marca = PedirMarca();
                string color = PedirColor();
                Coche coche = new(modelo, matricula, marca, color);
                Console.WriteLine(coche.ToString());
                lista.AgregarCoche(coche);
                break;
            case "2":       //lista.listarcoche()
                Console.WriteLine(lista.ListarCoche());
                break;
            case "3":       //lista.listarcoche(marca)
                string marca3 = PedirMarca();
                Console.WriteLine(lista.ListarCoche(marca3));
                break;
            case "4":       //lista + objetoCoche (sobrecargar el  operador + para que al sumar con un coche, el  coche se agregue al  array
                string modelo2 = PedirModelo();
                string matricula2 = PedirMatricula();
                string marca2 = PedirMarca();
                string color2 = PedirColor();
                Coche coche2 = new(modelo2, matricula2, marca2, color2);
                lista += coche2;
                continue;
            case "5":       // lista – objetoCoche (sobrecarga del operador – para eliminar del array el coche que se resta. Debe buscar el coche, si  existe será eliminador, en caso contrario mostrará un mensaje de error.
                
                continue;
            case "6":       //Salir del menú
                Console.WriteLine("Saliendo...");
                ejercicio = false;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("No ha introducido un número válido.");
                continue;
        }
    }
    while (ejercicio == true);
```

A continuación pego un fragmento de la clase coche con sus atributos, propiedades y constructores:

```
    #region ATRIBUTOS
    protected string modelo;
    protected string matricula;
    protected string marca;
    protected string color;
    #endregion

    #region PROPIEDADES
    public string Modelo => modelo;
    public string Matricula => matricula;
    public string Marca => marca;
    public string Color => color;
    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORES
    //los que vea necesarios
    public Coche()
    {
    }
    public Coche(string modelo, string matricula, string marca, 
string color)
    {
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Coloca en tu pregunta lo que has intentado. Ya que puede ser que el vomportamiento que deseas para tus objetos se pueda programar en un tipo valor, que se declare con `struct`, con lo vual no necesitarias invocar constructor, sino declarar la variable

Comment: Como estoy empezando, me gustaría conocer como se haría llamando al constructor y añadiendo el nombre del objeto por consola, pero añado el bucle para que lo veas

Comment: De cualquier modo para responder a tu pregunta se requiere saber cual es el constructor de tu clase, si tiene constructor sin parámetros, o si requiere parámetros

Comment: tiene vacío y constructor con todos los parámetros

Comment: Piblique, con su pregunta, el código de su clase, incluidos todos los constructores. También el fragmento de código donde pretende colocar el bucle, colocando con comentarios lo que pretende como /*Estas son las variables para referenciar los n objetps que deseo construir*/, /*Aqui deseo que se construya la instancia de cada objeto*/

Comment: Y cual de las opciones del menú debería crear los coches en bucle? Yo veo que tiene todo lo necesario una `List<Coche> lista` que debe estar declarada fuera del `do` o como variable local (si el codigo que publica esta en el `main`). Si lo que necesita es ejecutar el cuerpo que tiene en el `case 1` varias veces en una opción `7. Crear varios coches` debe sacar el cuerpo del `case 1` a un `Factory Method` `Coche CrearCoche()` q captura las propiedades , instancia un objeto `Coche` y lo retorna. Así lo invoca en el.`case 1` agregando la nueva instancia a `lista`; y en `case 7` dentro de un ciclo

Comment: Tu codigo tiene todo lo necesario y es correcto. Que parte no entendes y sentis que te falta?

Comment: @multiclaseq lo que podes hacer es almacenar tus objetos en un diccionario o en un array, no vas a poder crear dinamicamente el nombre de la variable. Creo que el diccionario es mejor en tu caso ya que como "identificador" te viene de la consola lo pones como Key del diccionario y luego podes acceder a ese objeto con ese "identificador"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer para no tener que modificar tanto el código es guardar tus objetos en un diccionario, de esta manera tendrías como key el nombre del objeto y por el otro lado como value el objeto como tal, te quedaría así:

Antes de entrar al `do while` inicializa un diccionario

```
Dictionary<string, Coche> listaCoches = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Luego dentro del case donde agregas un nuevo coche haz lo siguiente

```
Console.WriteLine("Introduzca un identificador para el coche:");
var identificador = Console.ReadLine();
...
listaCoches.Add(identificador,coche);
```

Para acceder a los objetos del diccionario puedes usar lo siguiente

```
var coche = listaCoches[identificador];
```

De esta manera guardas los objetos en el diccionario, (llave-valor) para que puedas acceder al nombre del coche de una manera mas sencilla.

referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: Esta solucion estaba pensando tambien, solo le agregue como acceder a los objetos del diccionario y una referencia. Saludos